# Observer with switch : The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this error at the beginning of my Observer widget at '{'. I tried break statements as well .
What am I doing wrong ?

```
     Observer(builder: (_) {
                  switch (_argumentStore!.myTileShowBankedArgumentState) {
                    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState
                        .notSelected):
                      return RaisedButton(
                        disabledColor: Color(0xFFFFC4A5),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Text(
                          'Hello1 ',
                        ),
                      );
             
                    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState.Selected):
                      RaisedButton(
                        disabledColor: Color(0xFFFFC4A5),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                        onPressed: null,
                        child: Text(
                          'Hello2 ',
                        ),
                      );
              
                  }
                })
```

Comment: You're missing `return` in the second `case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return from the second case:

```dart
Observer(builder: (_) {
  switch (_argumentStore!.myTileShowBankedArgumentState) {
    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState.notSelected):
      return RaisedButton(...);  

    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState.Selected):
      // Add a `return` statement here:
      return RaisedButton(...);
})
```

If the error persists, you must add a `default` case:

```dart
Observer(builder: (_) {
  switch (_argumentStore!.myTileShowBankedArgumentState) {
    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState.notSelected):
      return RaisedButton(...);  

    case (showMyTileBankedArgumentSelectedState.Selected):
      return RaisedButton(...);

    default:
      // This will be reached if
      // 1) myTileShowBankedArgumentState is null
      // 2) myTileShowBankedArgumentState is neither notSelected nor Selected
      // You can raise an error or return an appropriate widget
      throw StateError("invalid state");

})
```

Comment: Glad to help! If my answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Comment: Thanks enzo ! Sorry I didnt reply earlier. I did upvote before. But says I need 15 reputation to caste vote.  Thanks again for your help